# Elastic Beanstalk: what's the best way to create folders & set permissions after deploy?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm running a Rails 4.2 app on Elastic Beanstalk, and need to set log permissions and create the /tmp/uploads folder (plus permissions) after deploy.

I was running two ebextensions scripts to do this, but on some occasions they would fail because the folder /var/app/current/ didn't yet exist.

I'm presuming this is because the permissions and/or folders should be created on /app/ondeck/ first so that EB can copy the contents over to /var/app/current/, but I'm interested to see if there's a recommended and more foolproof approach to doing this?

For reference, my two ebextension scripts were:

```
commands: 
    01_set_log_permissions:
        command: "chmod 755 /var/app/current/log/*"
```

and

```
commands: 
    01_create_uploads_folder: 
        command: "mkdir -p /var/app/current/tmp/uploads/"
    02_set_folder_permission: 
        command: "chmod 755 /var/app/current/tmp/uploads/"
```

Thanks,
Dan

Answer (score 11, accepted):

you should probably use files tag and not command:

```
commands:
  create_post_dir:
    command: "mkdir /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/post"
    ignoreErrors: true
files:
    "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/post/99_make_changes.sh":
    mode: "000777"
    content: |
      #!/bin/bash
      mkdir -p /var/app/current/tmp/uploads/
      chmod 755 /var/app/current/tmp/uploads/
```

it will be triggered after app deploy finished

Comment: By the way, for anyone else reading this, there's an issue with the indenting, the area from `mode: "000777"` downwards needs to be indented one level deeper.

Comment: Any idea how this would be done on a windows server?

Answer (score 4):

I've used the below stpes:

- Create a folder .ebextensions
- Creta a file .config
- Move .config to .ebextensions
- Edit the file .config, it must have the below sintaxe

  commands: 
      command1: 
           command: mkdir /opt/jenkins
     command2: 
           command: chmod 644 /opt/jenkins

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html#linux-commands

*** Pay Attention ***

You cannot run again command1 "mkdir /opt/jenkins", you will have a error, so you must do a test before.

Comment: To prevent an error incase you run it more than once (i.e. because the folder will already exist), and don't want to change the code after your first deploy, change `command1` to `mkdir -p /opt/jenkins` and below it add the following for good measure `ignoreErrors: true`

Answer (score 3):

What about using Container Commands?

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ko_kr/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html#linux-container-commands

> You can use the `container_commands` key to execute commands for your container. The commands in `container_commands` are processed in alphabetical order by name. They run after the application and web server have been set up and the application version file has been extracted, but before the application version is deployed. They also have access to environment variables such as your AWS security credentials.
>
> Container commands are run from the staging directory, where your source code is extracted prior to being deployed to the application server. Any changes you make to your source code in the staging directory with a container command will be included when the source is deployed to its final location.

```
container_commands: 
    01_set_log_permissions:
        command: "chmod 755 log/*"
```

and

```
container_commands: 
    01_create_uploads_folder: 
        command: "mkdir -p tmp/uploads/"
    02_set_folder_permission: 
        command: "chmod 755 tmp/uploads/"
```

Comment: What's the main advantage of container commands over regular commands?